# Receiving 404 error for assets in Github Pages Jekyll site

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, jekyll, github-pages

I'm attempting to set up a basic Jekyll site on github pages. The site in question currently is:
https://kculmback.github.io/kcfeatures-v2/

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/kculmback/kcfeatures-v2

My problem is that the site is not loading images or the css files from my assets folder, even though the link seems to be correct (as far as I can tell).

**Example link to image:**
kculmback.github.io/kcfeatures-v2/assets/img/Logo.svg (currently not working)

**Here is the image in the repo:**
github.com/kculmback/kcfeatures-v2/blob/master/assets/img/Logo.svg

This is my first time setting up a Jekyll site but as far as I can tell from everything I've read I've done it all right...

Here is the siteurl/url settings from my _config.yml file:

```
# Serving
url:     "http://kculmback.github.io"
baseurl: "/kcfeatures-v2"
```

Here is an example of how I wrote the link to CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/app.css">
```

And here is the resulting link when rendered by Github Pages:

```
https://kculmback.github.io/kcfeatures-v2/assets/css/app.css
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the url, but what it is *excluded* in the `_config.yml`:

```
exclude:
  - "/assets/"
```

The above line tells Jekyll to **exclude directories and files from the conversion**.

So the website is being generated without the assets directory, while the urls are ok.

You have to remove **`assets`** from the `exclude` list and it works.

Comment: So I removed the assets folder from the exclude & cleared my browser's cookies/cache, but still no luck.

Comment: @Kasey did you restart the server?

Comment: Well I think it just needed some time apparently. Everything is working now! Thank you for your help.

Comment: As a side note, is there a way to restart a server for Github Pages? I am unfamiliar with that.

Comment: @Kasey no AKAIK, but it is a good practice to test the site locally and then upload/waiting for Github to generate the site